# How to horizontally concatenate columns from different tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have **Table A** with one column City looking like this (first 10 rows):

**City**

```
    Torrance
    San Carlos
    San Jose
    Walnut Creek
    Carmichael
    Anderson
    Altadena
    Orange
    Palos Verdes Estates
```

And **Table B** with one column Name like this (first 10 rows):

**Name**

```
    Merrill
    Elm
    Blossom Hill
    Brandywine
    Altamont
    Hill
    Wapello
    Palmyra
    Via Almar
```

I need to get a new **Table C** with 2 columns City and Name
from the first 1,000 rows of Table A and the the first 1,000 rows of Table B.

The resulting table should look like this (first 10 rows):

```
+------------------------+----------------+
|         City           |      Name      |
+------------------------+----------------+     
| Torrance               | Merrill        |
| San Carlos             | Elm            |
| San Jose               | Blossom Hill   |
| Walnut Creek           | Brandywine     |
| Carmichael             | Altamont       |
| Anderson               | Hill           |
| Altadena               | Wapello        |
| Orange                 | Palmyra        |
| Palos Verdes Estates   | Via Almar      |
+------------------------+----------------+
```

The question is how to horizontally concatenate the first 1,000 rows of each table?

Comment: What is the logic of matching City with Name? Randomly!? Have in mind - rows in tables are not ordered in any way - so order of how rows returned is not guaranteed at all

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail. I'm not matching them. The separate tables are already ordered so I suppose getting top 1000 for A and top 1000 B would get the order they have been ordered to. The purpose of this is to prepare the data for machine learning which is not exactly matching one record with the other but more importantly the frequency of distribution. The A and B tables are already ordered so at the top are most frequent. I would check your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (also see my comments below your question)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT City, Name FROM (
  SELECT City, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos 
  FROM `project.dataset.tableA` LIMIT 1000
) a JOIN (
  SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos 
  FROM `project.dataset.tableB` LIMIT 1000
) b USING(pos)
```

If to apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableA` AS (
  SELECT 'Torrance' City UNION ALL
  SELECT 'San Carlos' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'San Jose' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Walnut Creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carmichael' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Anderson' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Altadena' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Palos Verdes Estates' 
), `project.dataset.tableB` AS (
  SELECT 'Merrill' Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Elm' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Blossom Hill' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Brandywine' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Altamont' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hill' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wapello' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Palmyra' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Via Almar' 
)
SELECT City, Name FROM (
  SELECT City, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos 
  FROM `project.dataset.tableA` LIMIT 1000
) a JOIN (
  SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos 
  FROM `project.dataset.tableB` LIMIT 1000
) b USING(pos)
```

result is

```
Row City                    Name     
1   Torrance                Merrill  
2   San Carlos              Elm  
3   San Jose                Blossom Hill     
4   Walnut Creek            Brandywine   
5   Carmichael              Altamont     
6   Anderson                Hill     
7   Altadena                Wapello  
8   Orange                  Palmyra  
9   Palos Verdes Estates    Via Almar
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you Mikhail. Your answers are always very good.